# In Java, using Scanner, Is there a way to find a specific String in a CSV file, use it as a column header and return all values under it?

Tags: java, csv, java.util.scanner

I am trying to find the String "5464" in a csv document then have it return all of the values under that String (same number of Delimiters from the start of the line), until reaching the end of the list (no more values in the column). Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class SearchNdestroyV2 {


    private static Scanner x;


    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        String filepath = "tutorial.txt";
        String searchTerm = "5464"

        readRecord(searchTerm,filepath);
    }

    public void readRecord(String searchTerm, String filepath)
    {
        boolean found = false;
        String ID = ""; String ID2 = ""; String ID3 = "";

    }
        try 
        {
            x = new Scanner(new File(filepath));
            x.useDelimeter("[,\n]");

            while(x.hasNext() && !found )
            {
                ID = x.next();
                ID2 = x.nextLine();
                ID3 = x.nextLine();

                if(ID.equals(searchTerm))
                {
                    found = true;
                }

            }

            if (found)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ID: " + ID + "ID2: " + ID2 + "ID3: "+ID3);
            }
        }   
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error:");
            }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    {  
}
```

Comment: a) Never silently swallow Exceptions `catch(Exception e)
        {

        }`  b) Use a CSVReader

Comment: If you're looking for help and you're going to provide code, at the very least make an attempt to provide code that will compile. Fix your code.

Comment: I am sorry. I am 69 years old and so I have some trouble seeing the screen in the evenings!

Comment: @ScaryWombat Do you have any resources that could help me learn what it is that you mean?

Comment: Google is a good resource ;-)  Try searching for *java csvreader*

Comment: Also, Bruce it is maybe a good idea to plot out the logic that you are wanting to use on paper before starting to code.

Comment: Change `catch(Exception e) { }` to `catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e.printStackTrace());}` - this is print out the errors

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure of what you mean. The way I read your question:

You want to locate a specific String ("5464") that is contained within a specific column within a comma (,) delimited CSV file. If this specific string (search term) is found then retrieve all other values contained within the same column for the rest of the CSV file records from the point of location. Here is how:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SearchNDestroyV2 {

    private Scanner fileInput;


    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        // Do this if you don't want to deal with statics
        new SearchNDestroyV2().startApp(args);
    }

    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        String filepath = "tutorial.txt";
        String searchTerm = "5464";

        readRecord(searchTerm, filepath);
    }

    public void readRecord(String searchTerm, String filepath) {
        try {
            fileInput = new Scanner(new File(filepath));
       
            // Variable to hold each file line data read.
            String line;         
        
            // Used to hold the column index value to 
            // where the found search term is located.
            int foundColumn = -1;
        
            // An ArrayList to hold the column values retrieved from file.
            ArrayList<String> columnList = new ArrayList<>();
        
            // Read file to the end...
            while(fileInput.hasNextLine()) {
                // Read in file - 1 trimmed line per iteration
                line = fileInput.nextLine().trim(); 
            
                //Skip blank lines (if any).
                if (line.equals("")) {
                    continue;
                }
            
                // Split the curently read line into a String Array 
                // based on  the comma (,) delimiter
                String[] lineParts = line.split("\\s{0,},\\s{0,}"); // Split on any comma/space situation.
            
                // Iterate through the lineParts array to see if any 
                // delimited portion equals the search term.
                for (int i = 0; i < lineParts.length; i++) {
                    /* This IF statement will always accept the column data and
                       store it if the foundColumn variable equals i OR the current
                       column data being checked is equal to the search term. 
                       Initially when declared, foundColumn equals -1* and will 
                       never equal i unless the search term is indeed found. */
                    if (foundColumn == i || lineParts[i].equals(searchTerm)) {
                        // Found a match
                        foundColumn = i;                // Hold the column index number of the found item.
                        columnList.add(lineParts[i]);   // Add the found item to the List.
                        break;                          // Get out of this loop. Don't need it anymore for this line.    
                    }
                }    

            }

            if (foundColumn != -1) {
                System.out.println("Items Found:" + System.lineSeparator() + 
                                   "============");
                for (String str : columnList) {
                    System.out.println(str);
                }
            }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can't find the Search Term: " + searchTerm);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

If however, what you want is to search through the CSV file and as soon as any particular column equals the Search Term ("5464") then simply store the CSV line (all its data columns) which contains that Search Term. Here is how:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class SearchNDestroyV2 {

    /* A JFrame used as Parent for displaying JOptionPane dialogs.
       Using 'null' can allow the dialog to open behind other open
       applications (like the IDE). This ensures that it will be
       displayed above all other applications at center screen.  */
    JFrame iFRAME = new JFrame();                  
    {
        iFRAME.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        iFRAME.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        iFRAME.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Do this if you don't want to deal with statics
        new SearchNDestroyV2().startApp(args);
    }

    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        String filepath = "tutorial.txt";
        String searchTerm = "5464";
    
        ArrayList<String> recordsFound = readRecord(searchTerm, filepath);

        /* Display any records found where a particular column 
           matches the Search Term.     */
        if (!recordsFound.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Records Found:" + System.lineSeparator()
                    + "==============");
            for (String str : recordsFound) {
                System.out.println(str);
            }
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(iFRAME, "Can't find the Search Term: " + searchTerm);
            iFRAME.dispose();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns an ArrayList (of String) of any comma delimited CSV file line
     * records which contain any column matching the supplied Search Term.<br>
     *
     * @param searchTerm (String) The String to search for in all Record
     *                   columns.<br>
     *
     * @param filepath   (String) The CSV (or text) file that contains the data
     *                   records.<br>
     *
     * @return ({@code ArrayList<String>}) An ArrayList of String Type which
     *         contains the file line records where any particular column
     *         matches the supplied Search Term.
     */
    public ArrayList<String> readRecord(String searchTerm, String filepath) {
        // An ArrayList to hold the line(s) retrieved from file 
        // that match the search term.
        ArrayList<String> linesList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Try With Resourses used here to auto-close the Scanner reader.
        try (Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File(filepath))) {
            // Variable to hold each file line data read.
            String line;

            // Read file to the end...
            while (fileInput.hasNextLine()) {
                // Read in file - 1 trimmed line per iteration
                line = fileInput.nextLine().trim();

                //Skip blank lines (if any).
                if (line.equals("")) {
                    continue;
                }

                // Split the curently read line into a String Array
                // based on  the comma (,) delimiter
                String[] lineParts = line.split("\\s{0,},\\s{0,}"); // Split on any comma/space situation.

                // Iterate through the lineParts array to see if any
                // delimited portion equals the search term.
                for (int i = 0; i < lineParts.length; i++) {
                    if (lineParts[i].equals(searchTerm)) {
                        // Found a match
                        linesList.add(line);   // Add the found line to the List.
                        break;                 // Get out of this loop. Don't need it anymore for this line.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

        return linesList;  // Return the ArrayList
    }
}
```

Please try to note the differences between the two code examples. In particular how the file reader (Scanner object) is closed, etc.